# xs:import schemaLocation redirect not followed/https not supported in lxml?

Tags: python, xml, https, xsd, lxml

We've recently moved to an https-everywhere policy on our production infrastructure, and it's causing some problems with XML schema validation, which I wonder if anyone can help me clarify.

We have schema documents available at static paths on our server, and they were once available at http://path.to/schema.xsd.  They are no longer available there, instead being at https://path.to/schema.xsd, but any calls to the original URL result in a 301 (Moved Permanently).

The schema documents themselves have references to each other, in particular there's a parent schema which includes the line:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://example.com/schemas/iso_639-2b/1.0" 
   schemaLocation="http://example.com/static/iso_639-2b.xsd">
```

(note that the schemaLocation points to the http version of the URL still, as we weren't anticipating having to change this, what with the redirect in place)

In attempting to validate an incoming XML document against the schema

```
schema_path = "/path/to/file/on/disk/schema.xsd"
schema_file = open(schema_path)
schema_doc = etree.parse(schema_file)
schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_doc)
```

The root schema.xsd loads (since it comes from local disk), but on the final line, when we initialise an XMLSchema (using lxml as the underlying etree implementation) we get an exception:

```
{XMLSchemaParseError}element decl. 'language', attribute 'type': The QName value '{http://example.com/schemas/iso_639-2b/1.0}LanguageCodeType' does not resolve to a(n) type definition., line 41
```

My working theory is that lxml (or even the xml schema specification, though I haven't been able to find any documentation) either doesn't follow redirects or doesn't support https (or both!).

Any info, and advice on what the appropriate fix is would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am hitting the same problem now – since the DublinCore website decided to redirect everything to HTTPS.  The XML schema contains
`<import namespace="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" schemaLocation="http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/simpledc20021212.xsd"/>`, and this can no longer be validated by `lxml` because the URL changed to `https://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/simpledc20021212.xsd`. Have you found a solution?

Comment: We never did, in the end we created a special exception for our schemas that allow them to be served also under http. It looked like basically lxml did not (and still doesn't I imagine) support https.